# In how many parts an integer N (greater than or equal to 5) should be dissected so that the product of the parts is maximized?

Tags: calculus, discrete-mathematics

I tried using the AM-GM inequality and all I could arrive at was that the maximum value of product is obtained when all the parts are equal. How do I proceed after that? Any help is appreciated.

Also, apologies for not being able to use Latex. I am new to this site and still learning how to type using Latex.

Comment: Are the parts positive integers? Then show it is best to use mostly $3$'s, with one or two $2$'s thrown in if $n$ is not a multiple of $3$.

Comment: I am afraid the question does not mention anything about the parts. Also, could you please throw some more light on your comment? I am having trouble comprehending what you meant. (PS: I am still in high school, if that's relevant).
Thanks in advance.

Comment: We interpret the problem aa sking us to find pos. integers $k$ and $a_1,a_2,\dots,a_k$ such that $a_1+a_2+\cdots+a_k=N$ and $a_1a_2\cdots a_k$ is as large as possible. Here is a rough outline. If some $a_i$ is $\ge 5$, we can do better by splitting $a_i$. If $a_i=4$ we can split into $2+2$, or not, without changing the product. So for an optimal splitting we may assume that all the $a_i$ are $3$ or $2$. Note that  an optimal splitting can't have more than $2$ $2$'s. For any $3$ $2$'s (sum $6$, product $8$) can be replaced by $2$ $3$'s, leaving the sum unchanged but increasing the product.

Comment: I prefer not to write out a detailed solution, since I have seen this problem on MSE before, indeed more than once. You might consider using the outline above as a guide. If any detail gives trouble, please leave a message.

Comment: If the "parts" that $N$ is divided into need not be integers, then AM/GM tells you they are all the same, so we want to maximize $\left(\frac{N}{k}\right)^k$. That is a *different* problem from the one discussed above. I you are interested in that one, I can give an outline for a solution. Calculus makes things smoother for this version.

Comment: I think the question does not specify any condition on the integers, so it ought to be the last one. I understand that I could just maximize the function by differentiating and the apply the floor function to get an integer value. But the problem is, I was getting a discrete function. How did you convert that into a continuous function in the form of 'k'? 
Also, apologies for not making the question clear enough. 
Thanks.

Comment: Also, if you could provide me with a link to the variant of this problem which you just mentioned, it would be great.